# .zip file expands correctly on macOS, but on Windows it contains no elements

Tags: windows, mac

I downloaded an archive, expanded it on Mac, everything ok. The same archive when opened in Windows has no elements. Any idea how can this happen? The zip is not corrupted, I downloaded it more than once

Comment: Try another program to decompress the zip.  My first suggestion would be 7z.  Windows (unlike mac) offers your choice of programs to do things.. usually that works out.. sometimes it doesn't.  It's the price to pay for freedom.

Comment: It has to be said, there are alternative (de)compression tools for Mac too, if you find an awkward file;) Keka or BetterZip etc

Comment: Please note that the default code macOS runs to unzip files, does **NOT** check checksums, so if the file is corrupted (maybe the copy on the server you downloaded from was corrupt), macOS won't notice. macOS's "unzip" command-line tool, however, **DOES** check checksums (at least it did the last time I tested it). It would be interesting to know what happens if you use the "unzip" command-line tool on macOS, as opposed to using the Finder.

Comment: Since you’re downloading the file, the means it’s somewhere out there on the internet. Why not post the link so people could actually check the file, instead of guessing?